# How easy is to play many home pods simultaneously?

Tags: homepod

If I have 3 or more home pods, how easy is to play the same track simultaneously on all of them?

Can I just touch play from the Apple Music app? Or do I also need to specify everytime that I want to play on all devices? (by selecting each home-pod one by one in the list?)

Comment: Rather than close this as too broad (as we strongly prefer one question per question), I've edited this to not be a sequence of smaller questions. If you want to ask several questions, please just ask follow on questions linking here so people can follow the thread or evolution / synthesis of a larger question once the basics are answered.